# Node.js, Express, run a function AFTER sending a redirect

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple express function.

```
app.post('/thing', ensureLoggedIn("/loginpage"), urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
    var func = req.body.func
    res.redirect('/')
    somethingElse()
})
```

I want to return the web page, and *then*, do the somethingElse.

Surprisingly this just doesn't work. The web browser site there and waits until somethingElse is done, and then, reloads.

If I do this ...

```
app.post('/thing', ensureLoggedIn("/loginpage"), urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
    var func = req.body.func
    res.redirect('/')
    setTimeout(longRunningCalculation, 1100)  // sloppy but WTF
})
```

It "works" but obviously is crap.

By "works" I mean, the web page DOES reload instantly; then 1.1 seconds later the long process starts and works as expected.

(Bizarrely if I do a small time, like say "100", it "does not" work; it will, again, behave so that the web page only reloads, once, the long calculation is done.)

What's the solution?

Comment: "longRunningCalculation" sounds like something that might block the event loop. If so, you're never going to get it working like this because Node.js should be considered single threaded in this situation, and blocking the event loop will make it non-responsive for the duration of the calculation. You'll need to use something like [`node:worker_threads`](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html).

Comment: Can you post the code for your long-running calculation? I'd be interested to know whether it must really be executed on a separate worker thread, or whether it could be rewritten in a non-blocking way.

Comment: hi Heiko and Robert. the excellent answer to the question at hand, about Express, has been given by @sashok337.  it would be best to deal with unrelated issues on other questions, I'd say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that calling **next();** should help you. You can try to do following:

```
app.post('/thing', ensureLoggedIn("/loginpage"), urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
    var func = req.body.func;
    res.redirect('/');
    next();
    longRunningCalculation();
})
```

And you can look towards this to do things in more right way:

```
process.nextTick(() => {
  // do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Express has the ability to chain functions via callbacks so u can obviously send out response in one function and actually return in the next like below:

```
app.post('/thing', ensureLoggedIn("/loginpage"), urlencodedParser, (req, res, next) => {
    var func = req.body.func;
    res.redirect('/');
    next();
},() => {
//implement the long running calculation function 
    return;
});
```